# FIREBASE admin sdk doesn't return promises? Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, firebase, promise

So im looking over the firebase admin sdk( im fairly new at using node js and js in general). It was my understanding that most apis return promise objects in this language. why does firebase admin sdk methods set/ setvalue among others not return one? Should I be concerned performing the following code:

```
return admin.database().ref(`/users/${user.uid}/stripeConnected`).set(false);
```

without ANY error handling for it what so ever?

link to docs:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data

Comment: As I show in my answer below, the `Reference.set()` method *does* return a promise. This sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) though. Please describe what you're trying to accomplish and where you are stuck.

Comment: im not stuck, just trying to make sure im properly using this api as it needs to be used for production. Thank you for your response @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Reference.set()` method in the Firebase Admin SDK for Node.js returns a promise according to its [reference docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#set):

> `set(value, onComplete)` returns `Promise` containing `void`